# Does heterogeneous resistance have an impact on the zone diameter observed in disk diffusion susceptibility testing?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, antibiotics, antibiotic-resistance

### Question

Does the presence of small, discrete colonies within the zone of inhibition, suggesting heterogeneous resistance, impact the zone diameter in disk diffusion susceptibility testing?

### "Help us so we can help you"

ASM recommends that such occurrences should be ultimately interpreted as resistance to the antimicrobial:

> Distinct, discrete colonies within an obvious zone of inhibition
> should not be considered swarming. These colonies are either mutant
> organisms that are more resistant to the drug being tested, or the
> culture was not pure and they are a different organism. If it is
> determined by repeat testing that the phenomenon repeats itself, the
> organism must be considered resistant to that drug.
>
> https://asm.org/getattachment/2594ce26-bd44-47f6-8287-0657aa9185ad/Kirby-Bauer-Disk-Diffusion-Susceptibility-Test-Protocol-pdf.pdf

I can't see how this is a sound judgment as there is no way to tell that the persisting variants weren't initially among the inoculum population and didn't appear due to the antimicrobial exposure stress.

Then there is another question: does the presence of this occurrence in vitro also mean that it would ultimately appear in the different in vivo conditions?

Whatever the case, I want to know whether the emergence of such persisters would affect the zone of diameter or not.

It seems to me that it would depend on the mechanism of resistance to the antimicrobial in question: antimicrobials that are resisted by the organism in question through inactivating enzymes are the ones that can be affected. This is obviously because less antimicrobial concentration would be available for the whole population. Then, this is disk diffusion after all not the broth dilution method; organisms have access to the diffusing antibiotic gradient that passes through the part of the plate where they are located.

But if bacteria can't diffuse around (assuming non-swarming bacteria), what about their inactivating enzymes, could they diffuse away from the cells that released them in a significant manner? Then there is another question: shouldn't the appearance of persister colonies alert us to the possibility of additional, unseen microcolonies and could their produced inactivating enzymes affect the outcome of the zone diameter?

Edit:

> Still other significant resistances may be subtly evident and appear
> as individual colonies in an obvious zone of inhibition (Figure 12-9).
> When such colonies are seen, purity of the test isolate must be
> confirmed. If purity is confirmed, the individual colonies are
> variants or resistant mutants of the same species, and the test
> isolate should be considered resistant. **Bailey & Scott's Diagnostic Microbiology**

Does a purity plate with monogenetic phenotypic variants considered pure in this context?